# JavaScript-Canvas Стрельба

Tags: javascript, разработка-игр, canvas

помогите научиться реализовывать стрельбу, как на этой гифке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

не смог найти в гугле, что-нибудь путное по этому поводу

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("d1");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// кнопки
var pressedLeft = false; // лево
var pressedRight = false; // право
var pressedSpace = false; // пробел

// параметры игрока
var playerWidth = 20;
var playerHeight = 20;

var playerX = (canvas.width - playerWidth)/2;
var playerY = canvas.height - 25;

//параметры пули
var bulletWidth = 5;
var bulletHeight = 5;

var bulletX = playerX;
var bulletY = playerY;

document.addEventListener("keydown", KeyDown, false);
document.addEventListener("keyup", KeyUp, false);


// кнока нажата
function KeyDown(e) {
 if(e.keyCode == 37) {
   pressedLeft = true;
  }
  else if(e.keyCode == 39) {
   pressedRight = true;
  }
  else if(e.keyCode == 32) {
   pressedSpace = true;
  }
}

// кнопка не нажата
function KeyUp(e) {
 if(e.keyCode == 37) {
   pressedLeft = false;
  }
  else if(e.keyCode == 39) {
   pressedRight = false;
  }
  else if(e.keyCode == 32) {
   pressedSpace = false;
  }
}

// рисуем игрока
function drawPlayer() {
 ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.fillRect(playerX, playerY, playerWidth, playerHeight);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

// рисуем пулю
function drawBullet() {
 ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
  ctx.fillRect(playerX, playerY, bulletWidth, bulletHeight); // не уверен что это правильная строчка
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

function draw() {
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
drawPlayer();
drawBullet();

if(pressedLeft && 0 < playerX) {
 playerX -= 5;
}

if(pressedRight &&  playerX < canvas.width - playerWidth) {
 playerX += 5;
}

}

setInterval(draw, 10);
```

```css
#d1 {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="d1" width="250" height="250" ></canvas>
```

стрельба должна происходить по нажатию на пробел.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Примерно так:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("d1");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// кнопки
var pressedLeft = false; // лево
var pressedRight = false; // право
var pressedSpace = false; // пробел

// параметры игрока
var playerWidth = 20;
var playerHeight = 20;

var playerX = (canvas.width - playerWidth)/2;
var playerY = canvas.height - 25;

//параметры пули
var bulletWidth = 5;
var bulletHeight = 5;

var bulletX = playerX;
var bulletY = playerY;

document.addEventListener("keydown", KeyDown, false);
document.addEventListener("keyup", KeyUp, false);

// кнока нажата
function KeyDown(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 32) {
   pressedSpace = true;
  }

  if(e.keyCode == 37) {
   pressedLeft = true;
  }else if(e.keyCode == 39) {
   pressedRight = true;
  }else if(e.keyCode == 32) {
   pressedSpace = true;
  }
}

// кнопка не нажата
function KeyUp(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 32) {
   pressedSpace = false;
  }
 if(e.keyCode == 37) {
   pressedLeft = false;
  }
  else if(e.keyCode == 39) {
   pressedRight = false;
  }
  else if(e.keyCode == 32) {
   pressedSpace = false;
  }
}

// рисуем игрока
function drawPlayer() {
 ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.fillRect(playerX, playerY, playerWidth, playerHeight);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

const bullets = [];
class Bullet {
   constructor(){
      this.x = playerX;
      this.y = canvas.height - 25;
      bullets.push(this);
   }
   draw(){
      this.y--;
      if(this.y < 0){
          bullets.splice(bullets.indexOf(this));
      }
      // fillRect не требует openPath!
      ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
      ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, bulletWidth, bulletHeight);
   }
}


function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  
  drawPlayer();
  // рисуем пули
  bullets.forEach(bullet => bullet.draw());

  if(pressedLeft && 0 < playerX) {
    playerX -= 5;
  }

  if(pressedRight &&  playerX < canvas.width - playerWidth) {
    playerX += 5;
  }

  if(pressedSpace ) {
    new Bullet();
  }
}

setInterval(draw, 10);
```

```css
#d1 {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="d1" width="250" height="250" ></canvas>
```

Чтоб было совсем как на гифке, нужно еще добавить игроку время перезарядки игенерировать пули только если игрок заряжен (зарядка происходит по таймауту после выстрела)

Comment: клева  :D  держи плюсик

Answer (score 2):

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("d1");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var pressedSpace = false;
var pressedRight = false;
var pressedLeft = false;

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDown, false);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUp, false);

function keyDown(e) {
 if(e.keyCode == 32) {
  pressedSpace = true;
 }
 else if(e.keyCode == 37) {
  pressedRight = true;
 }
 else if(e.keyCode == 39) {
  pressedLeft = true;
 }
}

function keyUp(e) {
 if(e.keyCode == 32) {
  pressedSpace = false;
 }
 else if(e.keyCode == 37) {
  pressedRight = false;
 }
 else if(e.keyCode == 39) {
  pressedLeft = false;
 }
}

var bullet = [];

var player = {
 x: (canvas.width-20)/2,
 y: canvas.height - 25,
 pW: 20,
 pH: 20,
 timer: 0,
 bullets: 0,
 draw: function() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(this.x, this.y, this.pW, this.pH);
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
 }
}

var dBullet = {
 draw: function() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(bullet[i].x, bullet[i].y, 5, 5);
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
 }
}

function draw() {
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 for (i = 0; i < bullet.length; i++) {
  bullet[i].x += bullet[i].vx;
  bullet[i].y -= bullet[i].vy
  dBullet.draw();
 }
 player.timer++;
  
 if(player.timer % 12 == 0) {
  player.bullets = 0;
 }
  
 if(pressedSpace) {
  if(player.bullets < 5) {
   bullet.push
   ( {
    x: player.x + player.pW/2 - 5/2,
    y: player.y,
    vx: 0,
    vy: 10,
   } );
  player.bullets++;
  }
 }
  
 player.draw();
    
 if(pressedRight && 0 < player.x) {
  player.x -= 3;
 }
    
 if(pressedLeft && player.x < canvas.width - player.pW) {
  player.x += 3;
 }
}


setInterval(draw, 1000/60);
```

```css
#d1 {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="d1" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```